# How to convey current thread's bindings to another thread?

Tags: concurrency, common-lisp, sbcl, dynamic-variables

How to convey all of the current thread's bindings to another thread? To be specific, I need the following snippet to print `2` (not `1`) to stdout:

```
(defvar *foo* 1)

(let ((*foo* 2))
  (bordeaux-threads:make-thread (lambda () (print *foo*)))) ;; prints 1
```

Of course I could copy `*foo*`'s value by hand, like this:

```
(let ((*foo* 2))
  (bordeaux-threads:make-thread
   (let ((foo-binding *foo*))
     (lambda () 
       (let ((*foo* foo-binding))
         (print *foo*)))))) ;; prints 2
```

but is there anything that will allow to copy all of them at once?

Answer (score 4):

The [API](https://trac.common-lisp.net/bordeaux-threads/wiki/ApiDocumentation) is explicit regarding variable sharing:

> The interaction between threads and dynamic variables is in some
>   cases complex, and depends on whether the variable has only a global
>   binding (as established by e.g. DEFVAR/DEFPARAMETER/top-level SETQ) or
>   has been bound locally (e.g. with LET or LET*) in the calling thread.
>
> 1.
>
> > Global bindings are shared between threads: the initial value of a global variable in the new thread will be the same as in the parent,
> >     and an assignment to such a variable in any thread will be visible to
> >     all threads in which the global binding is visible.
>
> 2.
>
> > Local bindings are local to the thread they are introduced in, 
> >     except that
>
> 3.
>
> > **Local bindings in the the caller of MAKE-THREAD may or may not be shared with the new thread that it creates: this is
> >     implementation-defined. Portable code should not depend on particular
> >     behaviour in this case, nor should it assign to such variables without
> >     first rebinding them in the new thread.**

So make the the binding global and not local seems to be the easiest (not implementation dependent) route.

@coredump also suggests to checkout the `*default-special-bindings*` list for a possible sharing methodology:

> This variable holds an alist associating special variable symbols with
>   forms to evaluate for binding values. Special variables named in this
>   list will be locally bound in the new thread before it begins
>   executing user code.
>
> This variable may be rebound around calls to MAKE-THREAD to add/alter
>   default bindings. The effect of mutating this list is undefined, but
>   earlier forms take precedence over later forms for the same symbol, so
>   defaults may be overridden by consing to the head of the list.
>
> Forms are evaluated in the new thread or in the calling thread?
>   Standard contents of this list: print/reader control, etc. Can borrow
>   the Franz equivalent?

Comment: See also the note about `*default-special-bindings*`

Comment: `*Default-special-bindings*` is the straightforward way. Falling back to global, effectively non-special behaviour does not seem advisable.

Comment: Are you sure it would be easier if you want to change a variable in the main thread?

Comment: I am generally sure that it would be easier not to change global variables at all (as opposed to a dynamic re-binding).  If you need communication between threads (or processes, or whatever), use channels/mailboxes/sockets/queues/whatever.

Comment: I didn't mean from a system design perspective, I meant for a quick and dirty little application "meant just for me". But I see your point, I'll add the warning in a bit.